# Invalid input when converting varchar column to UUID

Tags: postgresql

I would like to change data type of a column in PostgreSQL:

```
alter column camelCaseColumn TYPE uuid USING uuid(camelCaseColumn)
```

But I can't seem to find a way to do it. The trouble is when I use double quotes in `uuid` call, I get an error:

> invalid input syntax for uuid: ""

Is there something wrong with my approach or is there a way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message seems to indicate that you are converting from a text (or varchar) column to uuid and you have empty strings (`''`) in that column. In that case you need to treat them as NULL. The name of the column is irrelevant for that error.

```
alter column camelCaseColumn TYPE uuid USING uuid(nullif(camelCaseColumn, ''));
```

---

However, if you really created mixed cased columns (which is a bad idea to start with) you have to use double quotes to refer to them:

```
alter column "camelCaseColumn" TYPE uuid USING uuid(nullif("camelCaseColumn", ''));
```

Comment: Thanks, man, I never considered a possibility of this being a runtime error.